I extracted a file from inside the dump that contains the serial number and I need to analyze it
I extracted a file from inside the dump that contains the serial number and I need to analyze it
I want to unpack and compress this encrypted file after modifying it

https://www.mediafire.com/file/32wowdk9phlhgrt/block-sn-hikvision/file

please do not comment on your own post ... if you have any additional information, then add it to your post ... do not write a comment

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
